# OpenCV remap interpolation error?

Tags: python, opencv, interpolation, remap, spatial-interpolation

I'm using opencv remap function to map an image to another coordinate system.
However, my initial tests indicate that there are some issues with the interpolation. 
Here, I give a simple example of a constant 0.1 pixel shift for a image that is 0 everywhere but at position [50,50].

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

prvs = np.zeros((100,80), dtype=np.float32)
prvs[50:51, 50:51] = 1.

grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(prvs.shape[1]), np.arange(prvs.shape[0]))
grid_y = grid_y.astype(np.float32)
grid_x = grid_x.astype(np.float32) + 0.1

prvs_remapped = cv2.remap(prvs, grid_x, grid_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

print(prvs_remapped[50,50])
print(prvs_remapped[50,49])
```

gives

```
0.90625
0.09375
```

However, I would expect 0.9 and 0.1 instead, given the linear interpolation method. Am I doing something wrong or is this some numeric issue? 
Are there any more precise remapping algorithms around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nice catch. Your expectations are correct in my opinion, as exemplified by `np.interp` giving `0.1` and `0.9` values.

Let's plot a pyramid (interpolating into the 49:51 square pixel range):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

prvs = np.zeros((100,80), dtype=np.float32)
prvs[50:51, 50:51] = 1

lin = np.linspace(49,51,200)
grid_x,grid_y = np.meshgrid(lin,lin)
grid_x = grid_x.astype(np.float32)
grid_y = grid_y.astype(np.float32)
prvs_zoommapped = cv2.remap(prvs, grid_x, grid_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(grid_x,grid_y,prvs_zoommapped,cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

[image: result: pyramid with jagged edges]

Notice anything off? With a plotting grid of 200x200, there are very visible steps on the pyramid. Let's take a look at the cross-section of our result:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(prvs_zoommapped[100,:],'x-')
ax.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

[image: result: clearly piecewise-constant function]

As you can see, the result is a piece-wise constant function, i.e. there's huge discretization error in the output. To be precise, we see steps of `0.03125 == 1/32` in the result.

My suspicion is that `cv2.remap` is not meant to be used for sub-pixel manipulations, but for a larger-scale mapping from one grid to another. The other option is that internally precision has been sacrificed for performance improvements. Either way, you're not going crazy: you should be seeing `0.1` and `0.9` as the result of exact (bi)linear interpolation.

If you're not committed to openCV due to other tasks, this mapping i.e. 2d interpolation can be performed with various bits of [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html), namely [its parts made for 2d interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37872171/5067311). For your special case of linear interpolation on a regular grid, [`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) or something similar might be appropriate.

Or even better (but I haven't used this submodule yet): [`scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html#scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates) seems like exactly what you're looking for:

```
from scipy import ndimage
ndimage.map_coordinates(prvs, [[50.1, 49.1], [50, 50]], order=1)
# output: array([ 0.89999998,  0.1       ], dtype=float32)
```

Applied to the pyramid example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

prvs = np.zeros((100,80), dtype=np.float32)
prvs[50:51, 50:51] = 1

lin = np.linspace(49,51,200)
grid_x,grid_y = np.meshgrid(lin,lin)
prvs_zoommapped = ndimage.map_coordinates(prvs, [grid_x, grid_y], order=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(grid_x,grid_y,prvs_zoommapped,cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

[image: pretty smooth pyramid]

Much better.

Comment: Thanks. ndimage.map_coordinates works as expected.
The interpolation error seems to have to do with some performance optimization as you already said. See also http://answers.opencv.org/question/123197/how-to-increase-warpperspective-or-warpaffine-precision/

Comment: @JulianS. I'm glad it does, and thanks for the link, seems right.

Comment: Just some more follow-up: I re-compiled OpenCV and changed INTER_BITS in imgproc.hpp from 5 to 10 (as suggested in the link given above). Now the error goes down to 0.00391. The error seems to be 1/2^N, with N being an integer. However, it's 1/2^4 in case of INTER_BITS=5 and 1/2^8 in case of INTER_BITS=10. So it's not just 1/2^(INTER_BITS - 1). But just in case someone wants to increase the precision of OpenCV a bit and can't change to another library I thought it might be helpful.