# Numpy Resize/Rescale Image

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, resize

I would like to take an image and change the scale of the image, while it is a numpy array.

For example I have this image of a coca-cola bottle:
[bottle-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n63s2.jpg)

Which translates to a numpy array of shape `(528, 203, 3)` and I want to resize that to say the size of this second image:
[bottle-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQF7L.jpg)

Which has a shape of `(140, 54, 3)`.

How do I change the size of the image to a certain shape while still maintaining the original image? Other answers suggest stripping every other or third row out, but what I want to do is basically shrink the image how you would via an image editor but in python code. Are there any libraries to do this in numpy/SciPy?

Comment: can you show code for your numpy array?

Comment: [scipy.misc.imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)

Comment: @sascha Deprecated, according to the page you linked.

Comment: @ShpielMeister I cannot get IntelliJ to print out the numpy array fully, for some reason when outputs are large it puts ... in all the time, so I can only see part of the array output in the console

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Yeah, you can install `opencv` (this is a library used for image processing, and computer vision), and use the [**`cv2.resize`**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize) function. And for instance use:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg')
res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(54, 140), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Here `img` is thus a numpy array containing the original image, whereas `res` is a numpy array containing the *resized* image. An important aspect is the `interpolation` parameter: there are several ways how to resize an image. Especially since you scale down the image, and the size of the original image is *not* a multiple of the size of the resized image. Possible interpolation schemas are:

> - `INTER_NEAREST` - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
> - `INTER_LINEAR` - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
> - `INTER_AREA` - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free
>     results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the
>     `INTER_NEAREST` method.
> - `INTER_CUBIC` - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
> - `INTER_LANCZOS4` - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

Like with most options, there is no "best" option in the sense that for every resize schema, there are scenarios where one strategy can be preferred over another.

Comment: I've just tried out this code and it works! Just one change is that `dsize` should be `dsize=(54, 140)` as it takes x then y, where as a numpy array shows shape as y then x (y is number of rows and x is number of columns)

Comment: I try to avoid cv2, it swaps dimensions and loads in BGR channel format. I prefer `skimage.io.imread('image.jpg')` and `skimage.transform.resize(img)`. https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli I avoid skimage.transform.resize because you don't have control over the interpolation algorithm it uses. But, that may not be important, depending on people's use cases.

Comment: @Decker skimage.transform.resize provides some control via the 'order'-parameter. order=0 is nearest neighbour, 1=bi-linear, 2=bi-quadratic, 3=bi-cubic etc. No area mean or lanczos interpolation however.

Comment: @TapioFriberg ahh yes, I stand corrected; I see the algorithms defined under the documentation for skimage.transform.warp's 'order' parameter. 

At some point it might be helpful to update the docs to include references for the types, "Bi-quartic", for example, isn't defined anywhere else in the documentation, (as of Dec 10 2019) - a one-liner might be beneficial to future users.

Comment: @Decker won't it affect the image when the swapping is done from RGB to BGR?

Comment: cv2 is SIGNIFICANTLY faster than skimage. Like hundreds of times faster.

Answer (score 130):

While it might be possible to use numpy alone to do this, the operation is not built-in. That said, you can use `scikit-image` (which is built on numpy) to do this kind of image manipulation.

Scikit-Image rescaling documentation is [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html).

For example, you could do the following with your image:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
bottle_resized = resize(bottle, (140, 54))
```

This will take care of things like interpolation, anti-aliasing, etc. for you.

Comment: Thank you! This answer also works! Although I'm getting some issue with the `anti_aliasing` flag, it looks like it has been removed from the most recent version of [0.13.1](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=resize#skimage.transform.resize)

Comment: This returns image as **float** ndarray even if your original image is **uint8**

Comment: This is a nice technique because it works with any number of channels. I tried this with rgb data combined with a depth point cloud data and it preserved the relationship like I wanted.

Comment: @DarthEgregious, jakevdp -> it made my random noise data into single color when I resized  (137,236,3) array to (64,64) like the method you've described. Is this normal because it looks like it has lost all the information?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (64,64,3)

Comment: @sziraqui preserve_range=True can preserve the range
skimage.transform.resize(..., , preserve_range=True)

Answer (score 37):

One-line numpy solution for **downsampling** (by 2):

```
smaller_img = bigger_img[::2, ::2]
```

And **upsampling** (by 2):

```
bigger_img = smaller_img.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)
```

(this asssumes HxWxC shaped image. note this method only allows whole integer resizing (e.g., 2x but not 1.5x))

Comment: Great solutions to manipulate segmentation label masks where you really don't need/want the conversion to float64 that happens under the hood in skimage.

Comment: As an alternative to repeat you an also use `np.kron(..., np.ones((2,2,1)))` (for a `HxWxC` image), but I'm not sure which one is faster.

Comment: simplicity is genius

Comment: Thanks! This is a gold solution if you want to avoid the need for another library!

Answer (score 35):

For people coming here from Google looking for a fast way to downsample images in `numpy` arrays for use in Machine Learning applications, here's a super fast method (adapted from [here](https://scipython.com/blog/binning-a-2d-array-in-numpy/) ). This method only works when the input dimensions are a multiple of the output dimensions.

The following examples downsample from 128x128 to 64x64 (this can be easily changed).

Channels last ordering

```py
# large image is shape (128, 128, 3)
# small image is shape (64, 64, 3)
input_size = 128
output_size = 64
bin_size = input_size // output_size
small_image = large_image.reshape((output_size, bin_size, 
                                   output_size, bin_size, 3)).max(3).max(1)
```

Channels first ordering

```
# large image is shape (3, 128, 128)
# small image is shape (3, 64, 64)
input_size = 128
output_size = 64
bin_size = input_size // output_size
small_image = large_image.reshape((3, output_size, bin_size, 
                                      output_size, bin_size)).max(4).max(2)
```

For grayscale images just change the `3` to a `1` like this:

Channels first ordering

```
# large image is shape (1, 128, 128)
# small image is shape (1, 64, 64)
input_size = 128
output_size = 64
bin_size = input_size // output_size
small_image = large_image.reshape((1, output_size, bin_size,
                                      output_size, bin_size)).max(4).max(2)
```

This method uses the equivalent of max pooling. It's the fastest way to do this that I've found.

Comment: large_image[:, ::2, ::2] returns the image with resolution halved.

Comment: @LasseKärkkäinen but it doesn't downsample, it merely selects every other pixel. The difference is that the final function 'max' can be changed to select or compute pixels in slightly better ways (using 'min' or 'mean' for instance). Your method is useful (and faster), if that doesn't matter.

Comment: @L.Kärkkäinen what is the opposite of this to double resolution?

Comment: @rayzinnz `np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=0), 2, axis=1) `

Comment: Could replacing `.max(4).max(2)` with `.mean(4).mean(2)` work as a fast method for downsampling with linear interpolation?

Comment: @HockeyStick it should, but I remember it being significantly slower in my tests.

Answer (score 21):

If anyone came here looking for a simple method to scale/resize an image in Python, without using additional libraries, here's a very simple image resize function:

```py
#simple image scaling to (nR x nC) size
def scale(im, nR, nC):
  nR0 = len(im)     # source number of rows 
  nC0 = len(im[0])  # source number of columns 
  return [[ im[int(nR0 * r / nR)][int(nC0 * c / nC)]  
             for c in range(nC)] for r in range(nR)]
```

Example usage: resizing a (30 x 30) image to (100 x 200):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sqr(x):
  return x*x

def f(r, c, nR, nC):
  return 1.0 if sqr(c - nC/2) + sqr(r - nR/2) < sqr(nC/4) else 0.0

# a red circle on a canvas of size (nR x nC)
def circ(nR, nC):
  return [[ [f(r, c, nR, nC), 0, 0] 
             for c in range(nC)] for r in range(nR)]

plt.imshow(scale(circ(30, 30), 100, 200))
```

Output: [image: scaled image]

This works to shrink/scale images, and works fine with numpy arrays.

Comment: I think the nested list comprehensions are hurting readability

Answer (score 6):

For people who wants to resize(interpolate) a batch of numpy array, pytorch provide a faster function names [torch.nn.functional.interpolate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=interpolate#torch.nn.functional.interpolate), just remember to use np.transpose first to change the channel from batchxWxHx3 to batchx3xWxH.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled back upon this after a few years.  It looks like the answers so far fall into one of a few categories:

1. Use an external library. (OpenCV, SciPy, etc)
2. User Power-of-Two Scaling
3. Use Nearest Neighbor

**These solutions are all respectable, so I offer this only for completeness.**  It has three advantages over the above: (1) it will accept arbitrary resolutions, even non-power-of-two scaling factors; (2) it uses pure Python+Numpy with no external libraries; and (3) it interpolates all the pixels for an arguably 'nicer-looking' result.

It does not make good use of Numpy and, thus, is **not fast**, especially for large images. If you're only rescaling smaller images, it should be fine.  I offer this under Apache or MIT license at the discretion of the user.

```
import math
import numpy

def resize_linear(image_matrix, new_height:int, new_width:int):
    """Perform a pure-numpy linear-resampled resize of an image."""
    output_image = numpy.zeros((new_height, new_width), dtype=image_matrix.dtype)
    original_height, original_width = image_matrix.shape
    inv_scale_factor_y = original_height/new_height
    inv_scale_factor_x = original_width/new_width

    # This is an ugly serial operation.
    for new_y in range(new_height):
        for new_x in range(new_width):
            # If you had a color image, you could repeat this with all channels here.
            # Find sub-pixels data:
            old_x = new_x * inv_scale_factor_x
            old_y = new_y * inv_scale_factor_y
            x_fraction = old_x - math.floor(old_x)
            y_fraction = old_y - math.floor(old_y)

            # Sample four neighboring pixels:
            left_upper = image_matrix[math.floor(old_y), math.floor(old_x)]
            right_upper = image_matrix[math.floor(old_y), min(image_matrix.shape[1] - 1, math.ceil(old_x))]
            left_lower = image_matrix[min(image_matrix.shape[0] - 1, math.ceil(old_y)), math.floor(old_x)]
            right_lower = image_matrix[min(image_matrix.shape[0] - 1, math.ceil(old_y)), min(image_matrix.shape[1] - 1, math.ceil(old_x))]

            # Interpolate horizontally:
            blend_top = (right_upper * x_fraction) + (left_upper * (1.0 - x_fraction))
            blend_bottom = (right_lower * x_fraction) + (left_lower * (1.0 - x_fraction))
            # Interpolate vertically:
            final_blend = (blend_top * y_fraction) + (blend_bottom * (1.0 - y_fraction))
            output_image[new_y, new_x] = final_blend

    return output_image
```

Sample rescaling:

Original:
[image: Original Resolution 1280x720]

Downscaled by Half:
[image: Half Scale]

Upscaled by one and one quarter:
[image: 1.25x Scale]

Answer (score 3):

SciPy's `imresize()` method was another resize method, but it will be removed starting with SciPy v 1.3.0 . SciPy refers to **PIL** image resize method: `Image.resize(size, resample=0)`

**size** – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: (width, height). 
**resample** – An optional resampling filter. This can be one of PIL.Image.NEAREST (use nearest neighbour), PIL.Image.BILINEAR (linear interpolation), PIL.Image.BICUBIC (cubic spline interpolation), or PIL.Image.LANCZOS (a high-quality downsampling filter). If omitted, or if the image has mode “1” or “P”, it is set PIL.Image.NEAREST.

Link here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Comment: Unfortunately, imresize() is deprecated, it will be removed in SciPy 1.3.0

Comment: The question specifically states the image is a numpy array; you can't use Pillow on that.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any libraries to do this in numpy/SciPy

Sure. You can do this without OpenCV, scikit-image or PIL.

Image resizing is basically mapping the coordinates of each pixel from the original image to its resized position.

Since the coordinates of an image must be integers (think of it as a matrix), if the mapped coordinate has decimal values, you should interpolate the pixel value to approximate it to the integer position (e.g. getting the nearest pixel to that position is known as [Nearest neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation)).

All you need is a function that does this interpolation for you. SciPy has [`interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d).

You can use it to resize an image in numpy array, say `arr`, as follows:

```
W, H = arr.shape[:2]
new_W, new_H = (600,300)
xrange = lambda x: np.linspace(0, 1, x)

f = interp2d(xrange(W), xrange(H), arr, kind="linear")
new_arr = f(xrange(new_W), xrange(new_H))
```

Of course, if your image is RGB, you have to perform the interpolation for each channel.

If you would like to understand more, I suggest watching [Resizing Images - Computerphile](https://youtu.be/AqscP7rc8_M).

Comment: May not work based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy/37872172#37872172

Comment: Personally, always not recommended using OpenCV...

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_read = cv2.imread('filename.jpg',0) 
original_image = np.asarray(image_read)
width , height = 452,452
resize_image = np.zeros(shape=(width,height))

for W in range(width):
    for H in range(height):
        new_width = int( W * original_image.shape[0] / width )
        new_height = int( H * original_image.shape[1] / height )
        resize_image[W][H] = original_image[new_width][new_height]

print("Resized image size : " , resize_image.shape)

cv2.imshow(resize_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great that you want to help others by answering their questions. However, I do not see how your answer adds value compared to the existing answer that already uses `cv2` and uses a proper resize function instead of reimplementing a "sub-optimal" resize function that does worse than nearest neighbour interpolation.