# Resize screenshot with mss for better reading with pytesseract

Tags: python-imaging-library, pytesser, python-mss

I need to resize an screenshot taken by mss in order to get better reading by pytesseract and i get it done with pil+pyscreenshot but can't get it to with mss.

```
from numpy import array, flip
from mss import mss
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from time import sleep

def screenshot():
    cap = array(mss().grab({'top': 171, 'left': 1088, 'width': 40, 'height': 17}))
    cap = flip(cap[:, :, :3], 2)
    return cap

def read(param):
    tesseract = image_to_string(param)
    return tesseract

while True:
    print(read(screenshot()))
    sleep(2)
```

here its working with pyscreenshot

```
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pytesseract

while 1:
    test = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1088,171,1126,187))
    testt = ImageOps.fit(test, (50, 28), method=Image.ANTIALIAS)
    testt.save('result.png')
    read = pytesseract.image_to_string(testt)
    print(read)
    sleep(2)
```

And, i don't care about maintain aspect radio, works better that way with pytesseract.

Comment: You will need OpenCV to resize the pixels array, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121983/1117028 for an example.

Comment: thanks man! works perfectly with that example :P