# Python OpenCV: Scale Image because of change in resolution

Tags: python, opencv, scaling

I want to scale down an image I captured (screenshot) in a 3840x2160 display to that as if it was taken on a 1600x900 screen for template matching.

Is it as simple as doing:

```
old_screen_size=[3840,2160]
new_screen_size=[1600,900]
cv2.resize(img,(0,0),new_screen_size[0]/old_screen_size[0],new_screen_size[1]/old_screen_size[1])
```

or do I need to do something else/ is it not possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Resize/Rescale Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121916/numpy-resize-rescale-image)

Comment: no. In the question the person knows what size they want the image to be, I want a specific resolution not an image size