# Concatenate many small images to one big image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have a question. For example, I have 3 images (50x50px), and I need the images to be combined into one image (for example, the output is 500x500px). My problem is that I don’t know how to combine the images vertically every time when 3 images are filled horizontally. And so step by step. Right now I only know how to fill in two lines (once horizontally and once vertically). I will be glad to any of your help. Thanks!
Below is the code that does what I need, but I also want to be able to resize the image for a new row or column:

```
img = 'path_to_image'
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400))
for x in range(0, 400, img.width):
    for y in range(0, 400, img.height):
        new_im.paste(img, (x, y))
```

Comment: You can't fool me that easily - I know 3x50 doesn't make 500!!!

Comment: I meant that they need to be combined until the output image

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```py
import numpy as np
img_1 = np.ones((2, 2))
img_2 = np.ones((2, 2)) * 2
img_3 = np.ones((2, 2)) * 3

img = np.hstack([img_1, img_2, img_3])
# array([[1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.]])

new_shape = np.array([6, 12])
new_img = np.tile(img, reps=new_shape // np.array(img.shape))
# array([[1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.], 
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3.]])
```

If you want to additionally resize your image maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121983/7570817) might help you.

This approach is agnostic on how you get your `img`. The important thing is that you have to make sure that all combinations of initial images will add up to the final shape.

If you have images of shape `50x50` and a final shape of `500x500` and you combine always 2, 3 or 4 of them together you have :

- 500 / (2*50) = 5
- 500 / (3*50) = 3.33
- 500 / (4*50) = 2.5

So this wont work for you. 
You have two options, either you crop the pixels that don't fit or you resize the resulting image.

- 500 / (2*50) = 5
- 500 / (3*50) = 3.33  -> 4, resize / crop 500x600 to 500x500
- 500 / (4*50) = 2.5   -> 3, resize / crop 500x600 to 500x500

```py
import numpy as np
img_1 = np.ones((2, 2))
img_2 = np.ones((2, 2)) * 2
img_3 = np.ones((2, 2)) * 3
img_4 = np.ones((2, 2)) * 4
img_list = np.array([img_1, img_2, img_3, img_4])

# Get random combination of 2-4 images
img_dx_rnd = np.random.choice(np.arange(4), np.random.randint(2, 5), replace=False)
img = np.hstack([*img_list[img_dx_rnd]])

new_shape = np.array([6, 12])
reps = np.ceil(new_shape / np.array(img.shape)).astype(int)
new_img = np.tile(img, reps=reps)

# Cropping
new_img = new_img[:new_shape[0], :new_shape[1]]

# Resizing
from skimage.transform import resize
new_img = resize(new_img, new_shape)
```

Comment: I added a link for resizing the image. what is it than that you want to see? Could you explain again what you want to achieve?

Comment: I can have 2, 3 or 4 small pictures - it doesn’t matter. I need to make an output image of them (for example, 500x500px). But small images each time are randomly selected among themselves from the list and concatenated.

Comment: I edit my answer, I guess I understand your question better now. Is this croping / resizing your problem?

Comment: I can link with you via email for more detailed discussion the task?