# Resizing numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I downloaded a program and trying to run it. I am facing some issues due to deprecation of Scipy essentials.

Previous programs consists of code related to scipy. In brief the operations are as follows:

```
import scipy


scipy.misc.imread(filename)

scipy.misc.imresize(img, (299, 299, 3), interp='bilinear')
```

(Note that these lines are not in sequence as in program, I just wrote the steps where I am facing issue. The lines given above are exactly replaced by the lines given in code sample below.)

Since many of them are not available now. I searched and trying to change as follows [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread#comment95377195_47865626), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121983/2700041)

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
import cv2

img = matplotlib.pyplot.imread(filename)

img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(299, 299, 3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

But, i am still getting the following error

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
```

It seems that opencv just resize two dimensional images only.

Is there any simple option i.e., using single library, to perform the desired operations without producing any error? If not, how can I resize that image numpy array with bilinear interpolation?

Comment: `cv2.resize` says: **Resizing, by default, does only change the width and height of the image.**  That's why it's complaining when you give a 3 element shape, while expect only 2.  The old docs for `imresize` seem to expect to 2 values as well, but it may have ignored the 3rd.  The 3 is `channel/color` number, which shouldn't change with `resize`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Make sure the data type of your image is uint8.

If you want a change in the third dimension you can try numpy.reshape() function.

```
img = np.random.randint(0,255,(400,400))
img = img.reshape(200,200,4)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: 4 Channel]

In your case

```
img = cv2.imread("imagepath",mode='RGB')
```

Comment: What about 3 in last dimension?

Comment: If you want a change in the third dimension you can try numpy.reshape.