# Python - Want to scale pixel art UP or DOWN - with no degradation

Tags: python, image, scale, scaling

I've made a collection of works at a large resolution for print that I would like to scale down. But I would also like to potentially do the opposite as well.

How would you suggest I approach doing this with a 2304x2304 pixel image?

It looks as though if I make an image at 2304x2034 pixels I would need to convert a large square of 96x96 pixels down to a 1x1.

Within that one block of 96x96 it would all be one HEX colour value; so just track through the image and take the pixel value at x,y and then move to the next x,y coordinate?

Are there any python libraries that already do something like this?

Comment: SciPy or OpenCV?

Comment: OpenCV resize can do that for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121916/numpy-resize-rescale-image

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually found a good solution with pillow. I'm going to close it. Using img.resize((width, height), resample=Image.NEAREST) <- The resample portion is the key! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a suitable - to me - piece of code with Pillow.

```
img.resize((width, height), resample=Image.NEAREST)
```

This bit is the key.

```
resample=Image.NEAREST
```

Works like a charm!