# Reshape and fill a 2D array using another as a reference

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I have two 2D array consisting of a binary image segmentation one is the ground truth, the other is the predictions. Due to some missing of the starting data I have different gaps of the prediction arrays. I have to scale the prediction arrays to the groundtruth one. `fit_transform` from `MaxMinScaler` returns the exactly same array from the starting one, and I can't use numpy reshape something sizing less.

```
T_array = np.array(True2)
T_array.shape
(791, 1443)
T_array.size
1141413
T_array
array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]])
P_array = np.array(Predictions2_1)
P_array.shape
(790, 1496)
P_array.size
1181840
P_array
array([[1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.]])
P_array_reshaped = scaler.fit_transform(P_array, T_array)
P_array_reshaped.shape
(790, 1496)
P_array_reshaped.size
1181840
```

Comment: that would corrupt your prediction data

Comment: MinMaxScaler isn't intended to change the shape of the NumPy array. It is only intended to change the numbers inside the array, not the number of numbers. Perhaps you might have more luck if you treat the array as an image, and [re-scale the array as if it's an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121916/numpy-resize-rescale-image).