# Interpolating within a grid in python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a number of height values across a grid, specified in a series of lists:

```
[3, 1, -2, -3, -3] # x = 0m 
[2, -7, -14, -30, -39] # x = 10m
[46, 22, 5, -2, -8] # x = 20m
```

The example above shows a 40m x 20m grid in the form

```
[x=0y=0, x=0y=10...][x=10y=0, x=10y=10...] etc.
```

I need to calculate the height at a specific  x,y coordinate. I have looked at various interpolate functions and example but can't make any sense out of them - please help!

An example would be the height at x = 5m, y = 5m in teh grid above, which would be in the middle of the values 3, 1 2 and -7 (-1ish?)

Thanks

Comment: Is it what you need? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Comment: You may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html). The code below should do the job:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

# Original data (e.g. measurements)
a = [3, 1, -2, -3, -3]
b = [2, -7, -14, -30, -39]
c = [46, 22, 5, -2, -8]

x = [0, 10, 20]             # x-coordinates
y = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]     # y-coordinates

# Organise data in matrix
z = np.vstack([a, b, c]).T

# Create interpolation function
f_z = interp2d(x, y, z)

# Desired x/y values
x_interp = 5
y_interp = 5

# Collect interpolated z-value
z_interp = f_z(x_interp, y_interp)
print(z_interp)  # (result: [-0.25])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Transform into 2D array

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 1, -2, -3, -3] # x = 0m 
b = [2, -7, -14, -30, -39] # x = 10m
c = [46, 22, 5, -2, -8] # x = 20m

all_lists = [a,b,c]


grid = np.vstack(all_lists) # Edit: thanks @jochen for better code

>>print(grid.shape)
(3, 5)
```

Now you can access grid via x,y coordinates

`grid[1,1]` and etc

Based on this, you can create logic.

If x = 5, y = 5, then you can create square corners indexes by this:

indexes: x/5 +0, x/5+1, y/5,y/5+1  --->  by combining them you get [0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]

At the end you just feed grid with those indexes

```
SUM = grid[0,0] + grid[0,1] + grid[1,0] + grid[1,1]
```

Comment: The construction of your grid is unnecessary complex. It could be `grid = np.vstack([a, b, c])`
Your code actually constructs and allocates memory for 3 grids, discarding the first two.

Comment: thanks. I tried vstack and it just extended array, but with your code, it does it better

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [`interpolate.gridddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) function from [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html).

With below code you can get the any interpolation you want from your grid.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dataX0 = [3, 1, -2, -3, -3] # x = 0m
dataX10 = [2, -7, -14, -30, -39] # x = 10m
dataX20 = [46, 22, 5, -2, -8] # x = 20m
data = dataX0 + dataX10 + dataX20
points = list(itertools.product(range(0,30,10),range(0,50,10)))

outputPoint = (5,5)
outputValue = griddata(points=points,values=data, xi=outputPoint, method="cubic")
print outputValue
```

The example above give you the interpolation at `ouputPoint` `(5,5)`. And the output would give:

```
>>> 
-2.78976054957
```

Comment: You may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy)

Comment: The post you linked applies to most answers given here. Perhaps you could add it as a comment to the original question, so that it is more likely to get noticed by other readers?