# Plot heatmap from list of lists

Tags: python, plot, heatmap

Having a list containing lists (of different sizes) of variables:

```
res = [[0.01, 0.9, 0.46], [0.64, 0.24], [0.87, 0.99, 0.47, 0.75], ...]
```

(note that the actual lists contain ~3000 variables each)

And let's say:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, ...]
```

Is there a way to make a heat-map out of it, with the values from res on the y axis ?

This being for example the heatmap of one of one of the lists:
[image]

I would just like to to this for every list and have them all on the same heat-map

Comment: You mean res on y-axis and x on x-axis? You should explain your question in greater detail.

Comment: @rnso yes exactly

Comment: So length of x is same as length of res? Do you want to plot each x against mean of its corresponding list in res? Explain your question more.

Comment: @rnso Imagine a scatter plot. For each value on the x axis, it has a list of values from the res list on the y axis. Is there a way to make a heat-map of the whole thing ? Without doing any mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by doing the following:

```
y_ax = []
cpt = 0
for i, elem in enumerate(res):
    y_ax.append([i]*len(elem))

res_flat = sum(res, [])
y_flat = sum(y_ax, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to plot a heatmap, it's likely you will need to interpolate your data into a regular grid. The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022277/interpolating-within-a-grid-in-python) achieves this using `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`

When you have done this you could use [seaborn.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to plot a heatmap:

```
import seaborn as sns
res = [[0.01, 0.9, 0.46], [0.64, 0.24, 1], [0.87, 0.99, 0.47]]
ax = sns.heatmap(res)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Do you mean using interpolation to have all the lists become of the same size ?

Comment: Yes exactly, currently each list inside the overall list are different lengths. Once they are the same length its possible to plot using seaborn as described above or through something like plt.contour. The following [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-irregulardatagrid-py) explains how to contour plot irregularly spaced data in matplotlib, but it also has an interpolation phase first

Comment: Thanks for the help. However i came up with a solution to my problem, I will post it

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution!