# How to interpolate data with NaN - values using scipy's interpolation routines?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have some 2D data-arrays which I need to interpolate. `SciPy` offers some solutions to this, as nicely explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy). My data very roughly looks like a 2D parabola (as a function of x1 and x2), with the opening pointing downwards, as illustrated in Fig. 1 for a horizontal cut along x2=0. As you can see, there are no negative values (the datapoints are all exactly 0 there).

[image: Figure 1: horizontal cut along x2=0 of example dataset]

I wanted to perform cubic interpolation as I require smooth data. This gives a problem at the edges, resulting in "wiggling" or "overshooting" of the fit/interpolation, as illustrated in Fig. 2. Negative values are, however, not allowed in the following post-processing of the interpolated data (also the following overshooting to positive values where they should be zero need to be suppressed).

[image: Figure 2: horizontal cut along x2=0 of example dataset and interpolation; overshooting at the edges can be clearly seen].

I thought that a clever "solution" would be to simply set the values which are 0 (note that those are all exactly the same) to `NaN`, such that they are ignored by the interpolation. But using `SciPy`'s `griddata` and the `cubic` method is not working with `NaN`s. The `linear` method can handle this, but I need `cubic`.

My question is, am I missing something or doing something wrong that results in `griddata` not working properly with `NaN`s and the `cubic` method ?

An example code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp

def some_funct( x1, x2 ):
    result = -x1**2 - 2.*x2**2 + 60.
    result[result < .0] = .0
    return result

# define original (sparse) grid
N_x1, N_x2     = 20, 20
x1_old         = np.linspace( -9, 10, N_x1 )
x2_old         = np.linspace( -9, 10, N_x2 )
X1_old, X2_old = np.meshgrid( x1_old, x2_old )

# datapoints to be interpolated
z_old = some_funct( X1_old, X2_old )

# set 0 datapoints to nan
z_old[z_old==0] = np.nan

# grid for interpolation
x1_new         = np.linspace( -9, 10, 10*N_x1 )
x2_new         = np.linspace( -9, 10, 10*N_x2 )
X1_new, X2_new = np.meshgrid( x1_new, x2_new )

# perform interpolation
z_new = interp.griddata( np.array([X1_old.ravel(),X2_old.ravel()]).T, z_old.ravel(),
                         (X1_new, X2_new), 
                         method='cubic', fill_value=.0  # only works for 'linear'
                       )

# plot horizonal cut along x2=0
fig1 = plt.figure( figsize=(8,6) )
ax1  = fig1.add_subplot( 1,1,1 )
x2_old_0_id = (np.abs(x2_old - .0)).argmin()
x2_new_0_id = (np.abs(x2_new - .0)).argmin()
ax1.plot( x1_old, z_old[ x2_old_0_id , : ], marker='x', linestyle='None', label='data' )
ax1.plot( x1_new, z_new[ x2_new_0_id , : ], label='interpolation' )
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_xlabel( 'x1' )
ax1.set_ylabel( 'z' )
plt.show()
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Forgot to include the versions I am using:

```
numpy: 1.15.1
scipy: 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For monotone cubic interpolation, which does not overshoot, use `pchip` or `Akima1DInterpolator`