# Interpolation of gridded data values - python

Tags: python, interpolation, geopandas

**Question :** Is there a way to resample gridded values from a `geodataframe` to plot a smoother map?

**Details :** 
I am working with a 24x24 grid named `gdf`. Each `cell` of the grid has a `value` and an `id` as attributes:

```py
#gdf.head()

    id      values      geometry
0   1       52.390119   POLYGON ((653179.710 6859158.392, 653179.710 6...
1   2       52.390119   POLYGON ((653179.710 6858908.392, 653179.710 6...
2   3       52.390119   POLYGON ((653179.710 6858658.392, 653179.710 6...
3   4       49.592331   POLYGON ((653179.710 6858408.392, 653429.710 6...
4   5       52.390119   POLYGON ((653429.710 6858408.392, 653179.710 6...
```

This is the type of map I get when I plot it:

[image: Initial gridded data]

As you can see there are very harsh changes in the values from a cell to another in the plot and I would like to smoother that out.

*Is there a way to divide each cells into 2 or 3 sub-cells (horizontally and vertically) to get a grid of higher resolution and then interpolate the values to get smooth gradients instead of this? **Knowing that I am trying to keep the data as a `geodataframe` since I need to convert them into a `shapefile` later on**.*

---

I found a method that allows me to do it via `plt.imshow()` as there is an `interpolation` option ; which would give me exactly what I want but this only gives an image as an output, I cannot directly modify `gdf` with it:

```py
grid = np.array(file.data).reshape(-1, 24)[::-1]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 20), subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})

for ax, interp_method in zip(axs.flat, methods):
    ax.imshow(grid, interpolation='lanczos', cmap='RdYlGn_r')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy

Comment: Isn't it different? They consider scattered points for the interpolation in that post whereas I have gridded data with no missing values in between.

Comment: Take it this way. You can represent your gridded values as an array. You can "inflate" your array up to given ratio to have missing values (your known values are now scattered) that you would then try to impute using the answer of this post

Comment: I see, I will try that out. Wouldn't I lose informations if I turn a geodataframe into an array (especially the ```geometry``` information)? I'm not used to using them so I am a bit unsure.

Comment: Does `geometry` represents a cell's polygon ? If yes, because you have a square grid, it's pretty much redundant information, as you can recompute those values using just the min/max coordinate of your map. So using your interpolated 2D array of float you can create a new geodataframe with the `polygons` column as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement my comment, another way is simply to consider your grid as an image and use the `PIL` library:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = PIL.Image.from_array(grid)
w, h = image.size
ratio = 4
image = image.resize((w*ratio, h*ratio), Image.BILINEAR)
image.show()
grid = np.array(image)
```

You can use [different interpolation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) methods as well. To get your data back into a pandas dataframe:

```
# flatten your grid and get your values back into a column
pd.DataFrame(grid.flatten(), columns=['values'])

# add an id column that starts a 1
df['id'] = df.index + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to convert the ```grid``` array back into a DataFrame (or GeoDataFrame) while keeping the right order of cells so I can plot the output ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I managed to get the desired result!