# How to get rid of artefacts in contourplot contourf (smoothing matrix/ 2D array)?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, matrix, heatmap, smoothing

I have data in a hdf5 file with named datasets

```
#Data Aquisition and manipulation
file = h5py.File('C:/Users/machz/Downloads/20200715_000_Scan_XY-Coordinate_NV-centre_APD.h5', 'r')
filename = path.basename(file.filename)

intensity = file.get('intensity')
intensity = np.array(intensity)

x_range = file.get('x range')
x_range = np.array(x_range)
x_range = np.round(x_range,1)

z_range = file.get('z range')
z_range = np.array(z_range)
z_range=np.round(z_range,1)
```

where intensity is a 2D array and x_range and z_range are 1D arrays. Now i want to smooth the intensity data. The raw data looks for example like this:
[image: seaborn_heatmap]

by using `seaborn.heatmap`:

```
heat_map = sb.heatmap(intensity, cmap="Spectral_r")
```

When using `matplotlib.contourf` via

```
plt.contourf(intensity, 1000, cmap="Spectral_r")
```

i get the following result:

[image]

which looks oke, despite it is rotated by 180 degrees. But how can I get rid of the distortion in x and y direction and get round spots? Is there a more elegant way to smooth a 2D array / matrix? - I have read somthing about Kernel density Estimation (KDE), but it looks complex.

---

Edit: Result by applying ´´´intensity_smooth = gaussian_filter(intensity, sigma=1, order=0)```:
[image: scipy.gaussian_filter]

The points with high intensity are dissolving, but I want sharp intensity maximas with a soft transition between two values of the matrix (see first pic).

Comment: The flipped y axis can be corrected by setting your ylim. The "distortion" is based on the coarseness of your grid, but you can remove some of it by reducing your contour levels and/or adding a filter. A gaussian filter might work https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html

Comment: Oke thanks for the tip with the axis. When applying the ```gaussian_filter``` I get smoothed neighbouring data, but actually I want additional values between two grid points to make the transition from e.g. (x,y)=(17,14) to (18,14) softer and get rid of the box like look.

Comment: Then you should try interpolating your data to a finer grid.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I expressed my answer misunderstandable. I have 2d data and want to get rid of the box look by interpolating the given data. To do this I have found a really good answer by Andras Deak in the thread [Interpolation methods on different kinds of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37872171/5559779). Plotting is done by using the `matplotlib.contourf` I have gotten this:
[image]

The tickmarks must be changed but the result is good.