# Can the scipy version change scipy.interpolate.griddata results?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

My problem starts with **scipy 1.2.3** and its function scipy.interpolate.griddata which performs an interpolation and provides me a reference dataset. (I'm interested in cubic 2d interpolation see the test case below)

After updating scipy to **scipy 1.5.2**, I can’t generate exactly the same results as before...and the differences are not negligibles.
By testing previous versions of scipy made available in my anaconda distribution, I generate exactly the initial interpolated results if I install **scipy 1.3.2**.

So I think griddata or one of its sub-components was updated after **scipy 1.3.2**.

But I can’t find any explanation about it in the Scipy release notes: [Scipy.org Release Notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.html), nothing in the history for scipy/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py on GitHub [History ndgriddata](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commits/102cfa6cc55ece537fe5b0b72a7aae63c877b3b2/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py), nothing in the history for scipy/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx on GitHub [History interpnd](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commits/master/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx). Maybe I don't see something evident ?

Has anyone ever encountered this problem : updating scipy has changed the results given by scipy.interpolate.griddata ?

---

To make a test case I have borrowed some code from : [how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872171/how-can-i-perform-two-dimensional-interpolation-using-scipy) (thanks a lot)

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np


# scipy 1.2.3 or (scipy 1.3.2) reference dataset   
z_griddata_scipy_1_2_3 = np.array([[1.22464680e-16, 2.99260075e-02, 4.64921877e-02, 3.63387200e-02,
                                    -1.17334278e-02, -4.10790167e-02, -3.53276896e-02, -1.32599029e-02,
                                    6.57516828e-03, 1.46193750e-02, 1.29942167e-02, 4.60176170e-03,
                                    -1.02398072e-02, -3.13455739e-02, -3.89274672e-02, -1.15549286e-02,
                                    3.59960447e-02, 4.60537630e-02, 2.96438015e-02, 1.22464680e-16],
                                   [3.06593878e-01, 2.94590471e-01, 2.55311166e-01, 1.72704804e-01,
                                    6.75755257e-02, -8.71796149e-02, -1.69793095e-01, -2.16754270e-01,
                                    -2.45929090e-01, -2.64204208e-01, -2.83893302e-01, -2.86038057e-01,
                                    -2.52505900e-01, -1.93389278e-01, -9.70877464e-02, 6.22252315e-02,
                                    1.64062151e-01, 2.49498113e-01, 2.91797267e-01, 3.07425460e-01]])


# auxiliary function for mesh generation
def gimme_mesh(n):
    minval = -1
    maxval = 1
    # produce an asymmetric shape in order to catch issues with transpositions
    return np.meshgrid(np.linspace(minval, maxval, n), np.linspace(minval, maxval, n+1))


# set up underlying test functions, vectorized
def fun_smooth(x, y):
    return np.cos(np.pi * x)*np.sin(np.pi * y)


def test_griddata_cubic():
    # sparse input mesh, 6x7 in shape
    N_sparse = 6
    x_sparse, y_sparse = gimme_mesh(N_sparse)
    z_sparse_smooth = fun_smooth(x_sparse, y_sparse)

    # dense output mesh, 20x21 in shape
    N_dense = 20
    x_dense, y_dense = gimme_mesh(N_dense)

    z_griddata_scipy_test = griddata(np.array([x_sparse.ravel(), y_sparse.ravel()]).T,
                                     z_sparse_smooth.ravel(),
                                     (x_dense, y_dense),
                                     method='cubic')

    try:
        np.testing.assert_almost_equal(z_griddata_scipy_1_2_3, z_griddata_scipy_test[:2], decimal=5)

    except AssertionError as err:
        print (err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    """
    test_griddata_cubic()
```

---

The test result on my computer Windows 7, Python 3.7, scipy 1.5.2 :

```
Arrays are not almost equal to 5 decimals

Mismatched elements: 38 / 40 (95%)
Max absolute difference: 0.03821737
Max relative difference: 0.67726368
 x: array([[ 1.22465e-16,  2.99260e-02,  4.64922e-02,  3.63387e-02,
        -1.17334e-02, -4.10790e-02, -3.53277e-02, -1.32599e-02,
         6.57517e-03,  1.46194e-02,  1.29942e-02,  4.60176e-03,...
 y: array([[ 1.22465e-16,  2.97398e-02,  4.62030e-02,  3.61127e-02,
        -1.15711e-02, -3.85005e-02, -3.03032e-02, -9.36536e-03,
         3.92018e-03,  1.17290e-02,  1.37729e-02,  6.40206e-03,...
```

I can observe that the differences are not negligibles !

Comment: To pinpoint the relevant change, you could do the following. For each commit between the version where it still worked and the first version where the results changed, compile the `scipy` package from source and check if behavior changes. That way you can identify the relevant commit (given that it builds for that specific commit, otherwise you can at least identify a group of commits). This shouldn't be too difficult with the help of a little automation script to perform the uninstall, build, install and test steps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @a_guest. Your method is probably good to find the divergent commit. But I think I'm not skillful enough to perform such operation. All the more I work on Windows and it seems to be difficult and time consuming to build Scipy from source on this platform. However I will document myself and still think about your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the behavior is different already for version 1.4.0, running a bisection on all [commits](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/compare/v1.3.2...v1.4.0) between 1.3.2 and 1.4.0 and building SciPy from source for each commit + running the test script, helps in narrowing down to the relevant changes.

The result is that the change in behavior was introduced by [these commits](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/compare/f28544666cbc74c86c21fc2b320bc31f9fbd1c2c...18219f5a1971be9a3fd6d590aeb496a419e8cd0e) that apparently introduced a new `qh_new_qhull_scipy` algorithm. This algorithm in turn is used by the `griddata` function. According to [this commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/c7e7713358208eee4a0367f871c4b72d6d0edeb5), `qh_new_qhull` was previously patched, so most likely the new results that you obtain are the correct ones.

---

Here are the detailed steps of narrowing down to the relevant commits.

**Preparation steps:**

1. Create a new virtual environment.
2. Get the SciPy source code: `git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git`; and `mv scipy scipy-source`.
3. Install dependencies that are needed for [building SciPy from source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html) (+ `pip install tempita`).
4. Copy & paste the OP's code into a file `test.py` and remove the `try/except` surrounding the `np.testing.assert_almost_equal`.
5. Run the below `main` script (this will take quite long).

**The main script:**

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

def log(msg, *, level=0, newline=False):
    indent = '    ' * level
    print(f'{indent}{msg}', end='\n' if newline else '', flush=True)

def run(cmd, **kwargs):
    if cmd.startswith('git'):
        kwargs['cwd'] = 'scipy-source'
    kwargs.update(check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), **kwargs).stdout.strip()

def run_and_log(cmd, **kwargs):
    exc, *args = shlex.split(cmd)
    exc = Path(exc).name
    log(f'{" ".join([exc, *args])}: ', level=1)
    text = run(cmd, **kwargs).strip()
    if text:
        text = text.splitlines()[-1]
    log(text, newline=True)
    return text

python = sys.executable

ancestor = run('git merge-base v1.3.2 v1.4.0')
commits = run(f'git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline --reverse --ancestry-path {ancestor}..v1.4.0').splitlines()
commits = [x.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0] for x in commits]
log(f'Scanning {len(commits)} commits', newline=True)

low, high = 0, len(commits)
index = (low + high) // 2

while 0 < index < len(commits):
    commit = commits[index]

    log(f'{commit[:8]} ({index})', newline=True)

    run_and_log(f'{python} -m pip uninstall -y scipy')
    run_and_log(f'git checkout {commit}')
    try:
        run_and_log(f'{python} -m pip install .', cwd='scipy-source')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        log('build failed', newline=True)
        index += 1
        continue
    try:
        run_and_log(f'{python} test.py')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        log('failed', newline=True)
        high = index
    else:
        low = index
    if high - low <= 1:
        break
    index = (low + high) // 2
```

And it produces the following output:

```
$ python main.py 
Scanning 1281 commits
19f4c290 (640)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+18219f5
    git checkout 19f4c2900d6c62d1e56c2faecd8a2b1d584c094e: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+19f4c29
    python test.py: failed
983e83e5 (320)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+19f4c29
    git checkout 983e83e549a1c6f04b4657d2396dc47ab4b8d0e1: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+983e83e
    python test.py: 
a3276047 (480)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+983e83e
    git checkout a3276047bb3493eeab6dac5148615cc8010faac0: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+a327604
    python test.py: failed
35f86bc3 (400)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+a327604
    git checkout 35f86bc33016dc88fc4340e4dc3f23bf86e4f311: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+35f86bc
    python test.py: failed
7b0345e9 (360)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+35f86bc
    git checkout 7b0345e9c038d7c1082ec0097f1ed4a626734bf4: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+7b0345e
    python test.py: failed
f9525c3c (340)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+7b0345e
    git checkout f9525c3ce7a9b63afda23b0af2ad32c7fbcedaa9: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+f9525c3
    python test.py: 
4a71ecf7 (350)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+f9525c3
    git checkout 4a71ecf72be8321eb9a5faf7307f4c18cb0cb500: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+4a71ecf
    python test.py: failed
9b7879b8 (345)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+4a71ecf
    git checkout 9b7879b832aa52131383999fc7dd0dfa3575a4c2: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+9b7879b
    python test.py: failed
5481d175 (342)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+9b7879b
    git checkout 5481d175bb29d7162ac9eed18bb9181a2b566f20: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+5481d17
    python test.py: 
f2854466 (343)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+5481d17
    git checkout f28544666cbc74c86c21fc2b320bc31f9fbd1c2c: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+f285446
    python test.py: 
18219f5a (344)
    python -m pip uninstall -y scipy:   Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.0.dev0+f285446
    git checkout 18219f5a1971be9a3fd6d590aeb496a419e8cd0e: 
    python -m pip install .: Successfully installed scipy-1.4.0.dev0+18219f5
    python test.py: failed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_guest. You have found the origin of the changes I observed in scipy.interpolate.griddata. I don't think I would achieved to do this job. I have to improve myself with your answer.Thanks again. With some advance I wish you a happy new year 2021.