# 2D interpolation between two curves (arrays of inequal lengths)

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm developing an open source battery model, and I work with datasheets of different cells to use them in the model. The temperature characteristics of a battery look like this :

[image: Battery Temperature Characteristics]

When the data is sampled to numerical values, the resulting arrays do not have the same lengths :

[image: Numerical data]

I'm looking to perform a 2D interpolation in order to determine the voltage of the battery at a given capacity and temperature.

I struggle to find a good way to interpolate this kind of data. I do realize that interpolation between two arrays of unequal lengths might not be a well defined problem, but I'm trying to look for a solution which would provide reasonable results in this case.

I think that regularizing the data to a grid might work, but I suspect that it is not a very good solution in my case because of how uneven the length and shape of the curves is. I think it might cause the interpolation to be performed between two points that are far away and "do not correspond to each other" on the curves if you know what I mean.

Instead, I would be hoping for a kind of solution that would "extend" the triangular part of the dataset.

I would be very thankful if you can provide any idea that could help me find a solution.

**EDIT** : I will try to clarify the problem, sorry if I wasn't able to express it in a clear manner.

The input are the graphs from the datasheet, which are read into numeric values (let's say Excel/csv for storage and pandas datasheet for the Python code)

The output is a function that for any point inside the domain of definition (x=Temperature, y=Capacity), provides the interpolated value of (z=Voltage)

I do not fully understand the first question, but the confusion might come from the fact that I do not want graphs as outputs and I do not extrapolate any data.

I do not know which would be the best way to share the data, I think 170 lines might be a bit too much to copy-paste. I don't think it's exactly necessary either.

The point is that I sampled the curves on the graph for every 25 mAh of capacity. Since the battery is cut off below a certain voltage, the arrays have varying lengths : the 60°C curve ends around 4200mAh, while the -40°C ends sooner, around 3600mAh

**EDIT2**  N. Wouda : I hope it's allowed to share links, I uploaded the csv here : https://transferxl.com/08jXjy5T1814kr

Pranav Hosangadi : In such case, I would raise a Value Error

Comment: How are the graphs plotted on the entire range if you don't have them sampled on the entire range? By extrapolation? If so, and the plots seem reasonable, why would a regular grid (say, with spline) not be enough?

Comment: Also, Please post data as copy-pasteable code, preferably loadable by copy-paste into a dataframe.

Comment: And, post copy-pasteable code to create the plots from the data.

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand and you are trying to create these graphs you know to be correct from your incomplete data? Please define the problem as inputs as outputs.

Comment: Can you at least provide the data set (as a csv/excel)?

Comment: What do you want to happen if I try to get the voltage for -40C at 4000K?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are interested in a function U(Temperature, Capacity) (so a 2D fit)? This function would accept temperatures like 13.73°C and a capacity for which there are no input data available, and returns a voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SciPy has a module entirely geared towards interpolation, at [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). In the following code I use [radial basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation) to create an interpolating function. IMHO, these result in a somewhat smoother result than using e.g. `interp2d` directly, and obtaining them is quite economical when the data set is not too large. The downside is that radial basis functions need not respect the scale (min/max) of your data, especially not outside the initial domain. You should check for that before using the interpolant!

(see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872172/4316405) for a nice overview of the relative strengths of different interpolating functions)

Here's the code:

```
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
    

def interp(df: pd.DataFrame):
    temp = []
    cap = []
    voltage = []

    for col in df.columns:
        if col.startswith("Voltage"):
            temp.extend([_col_to_temp(col)] * len(df.Capacity))
            cap.extend(df.Capacity)
            voltage.extend(df[col])

    x = np.array(temp)
    y = np.array(cap)
    z = np.array(voltage)

    isna = pd.isna(z)

    return interpolate.Rbf(x[~isna], y[~isna], z[~isna])


def _col_to_temp(col: str) -> float:
    # Gets temperature from column name 
    res = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+', col)
    return float(res[0])


df = pd.read_csv("Molicel_Temperature.csv")
f = interp(df)
```

It is hopefully fairly straightforward. `f` is the interpolating function and takes a temperature and capacity argument, as e.g. `f(50, 2000)`, returning the interpolated voltage. This results in, say, the following graph for different values of `(temp, capacity)`:

[image: voltage interp]

which seems to be what you are looking for!